# Project Euler #34 Digit factorials

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, programming-challenge

I'm having trouble improving the performance of the solution to the Project Euler problem #34

> 145 is a curious number, as 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.
>
> Find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits.
>
> Note: as 1! = 1 and 2! = 2 are not sums they are not included.

I've done the following :

```
    private static readonly int max = (int)Factorial(9)*7;
    private static void Main()
    {
        long sum = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 3; i <= max; i++)
        {
            if (IsCuriousNumber(i))
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Time to calculate in milliseconds : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static long Factorial(int input)
    {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            sum *= i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static bool IsCuriousNumber(long input)
    {
        char[] digits = input.ToString().ToCharArray();
        long sum = digits.Sum(t => Factorial((int) char.GetNumericValue(t)));
        return sum == input;
    }
```

It's pretty much self-explanatory .. We have a method to find the factorial of specific number and one more method that checks if a number is "curious" as described in the problem above. We do this by simply converting the input to a `char` array than we have a variable that just sum's up all the factorials of the digits in the number.

Comment: For the record, these numbers are known as [Factorions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorion).  The series can be found at [A014080](https://oeis.org/A014080).  As there are only 4 of them (in base 10 anyhow), your function could simply look them up from an array instead of calculating it, which would be much faster, though that's kind of cheating a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code and it ran in 1397 milliseconds, so that's not something to worry about. However, there is something very inefficient about your code: you calculate `Factorial` for every digit you encounter.
Calculate them in advance.

You have declared your `sum` variable inside the `Factorial(i)` method as an `int`, while the return type is `long`. However, you are never dealing with a `long` value, so you can just change the return type to `int`.
(You're only calculating up to 9!, which fits well within the range for `int`)

Also, converting each number to a string and back again is kinda slow too.

```
class Euler034
{
    //Calculate the factorials in advance and just look them up.
    private static readonly int[] fact = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Factorial).ToArray();
    private static readonly int max = fact[9] * 7;

    public static void Main()
    {
        //Convenient method for creating and starting a Stopwatch
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i <= max; i++) {
            if (IsCuriousNumber(i)) sum += i;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Time to calculate in milliseconds : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private bool IsCuriousNumber(int number) {
        return number == Digits(number).Select(i => fact[i]).Sum();
    }

    private static int Factorial(int number)
    {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            sum *= i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Digits(int number)
    {
        while (number > 0) {
            yield return number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mine runs for ~1120, yours for ~800 it is improvement thanks, but I will still wait for more answer to come.. eventually with even greater performance increase.

Comment: Turning the `Select(...)` statement in `IsCuriousNumber` into a for-loop would improve it a bit, I guess.

Comment: It's actually working for ~500 ms when I changed it to `foreach` loop now that's much better almost halved your initial time.

Comment: It seems still needless complicated ... `enumerable.range.select.toArray` ... why not`{1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800}`

Comment: @edc65 That's actually what I did in my original code... If you don't know the numbers you need from the top of your head, you can always calculate them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to get digits of a number using integer math:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int number)
{
    while (number != 0)
    {
        yield return number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

In this method digits are enumerated in reverse order, but it doesn't matter. Moreover, we can take an advantage of it.

```
private static bool IsCuriousNumber(int input)
{
    var digits = GetDigits(input);
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int i in digits)
    {
        sum += Factorial(i);
        if (sum > input)
            return false;
    }
    return sum == input;
}
```

I've replaced the `long sum = digits.Sum(t => Factorial(t));` with `foreach` loop to be able break the loop as soon as a current `sum` value exceeds the `input`. Reverse digits order is an opportune moment here.

---

Also, you could store an array of calculated factorials for digits and eliminate the `Factorial` method:

```
private static readonly int[] Factorials;

static Program()
{
    Factorials = new int[10];
    Factorials[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < Factorials.Length; i++)
    {
        Factorials[i] = Factorials[i - 1] * i;
    }
}
```

In this case the `IsCuriousNumber` method looks like:

```
private static bool IsCuriousNumber(int input)
{
    var digits = GetDigits(input);
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int i in digits)
    {
        sum += Factorials[i]; // The only changed line
        if (sum > input)
            return false;
    }
    return sum == input;
}
```

---

You could also use the `Paraller.For` instead of `for`:

```
int sum = 0;
Parallel.For(3, max + 1, i =>
    {
        if (IsCuriousNumber(i))
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref sum, i);
        }
    });
```

Replacing `long` with `int` also speeds up the solution. Please revise.

Comment: I forgot to change the sum to `long` thanks for noting that however this doesn't improve the performance it works just 10-20 ms faster if not even none. I added the performance tag now.

Comment: @denis I've updated the answer. Please revise.

Comment: I tested the updated answer, it runs in ~640 ms Dennis_E's answer take's ~500 ms

Comment: @denis Probably it's because I use `long`s while in Dennis_E's answer `int`s are used. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to speed this up is to calculate the factorial of 1..9 and storing the values including `0`, `0` e.g in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` once.

Looking up the values in the dictionary will take less time then calculating the factorials each time.